# After connecting lodash, the function is not called

Tags: reactjs, iframe, addeventlistener, debouncing

There is a function that accepts an event and is launched using a debounce

```
const docsRichHandler = (ev) => {
      if (ev.data.type === "sendText" || ev.data.type === "sendLoadText") {
        try {
          handleChangeDocs(
            null,
            {
              value: ev.data.message,
            },
            docId
          );
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
    };

    const debounceChange = useMemo(
      () => debounce((e) => docsRichHandler(e), 500),
      []
    );
```

then I call addEventListener and call the method of the corresponding iframe

```
useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
        if (!getFrameByEvent(event)) return;
        try {
          if (getFrameByEvent(event).name === "docsRich") {
            debounceChange(event);
            return;
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });

      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("message", mainRichHandler);
        window.removeEventListener("message", debounceChange);
      };
    });
```

but debounce function is not called